# SU(n) is a manifold via charts

Tags: matrices, differential-geometry, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I'm trying to construct an atlas the painful way for $SU(n)$, using charts. According to Wiki, SU(n) is a real manifold of real dimension $n^2-1$; I can believe this because you can perform a Cayley Transformation for any $U \in SU(n)$ such that the map $C:M_n(\mathbb{C})^{*}\longrightarrow M_n(\mathbb{C})$

$$ C : U \longmapsto C(U) = (1_n - U)(1_n+U)^{-1} 
$$

Which is well defined because any unimodular unitary matrices are non exceptional (that is that have $\det(1_n+U)\neq 0$). Thus the Cayley transformation defines a homeomorphism, given that you can use the Lie algebra

$$\mathfrak{su}(n) = \{X \in GL_n(\mathbb{C}): X^{\dagger}+X=0,\; Tr(X)=0\}
$$

to explicitly compute the dimension.

But what I want to try is to find explicit charts for these guys. This is what I've tried so far (restricting to $SU(3)$ to see the machinery involved); given that

$$SU(3) = \left\{\;\;\left(\begin{smallmatrix}a&b& c\\ d & e & f\\ g & h & i\end{smallmatrix}\right) \; \left| \right. \left(\begin{smallmatrix}a&b& c\\ d & e & f\\ g & h & i\end{smallmatrix}\right)^{\dagger}\left(\begin{smallmatrix}a&b& c\\ d & e & f\\ g & h & i\end{smallmatrix}\right)=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0&0\\ 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{smallmatrix}\right) \; \& \;|ei-hf|^2+|gf-di|^2+|dh-ge|^2 +|dh-ge|^2=1    \;\;\right\}
$$

Where you get a whole bunch of conditions from the unitary conditions, and thus a whole set of equivalent conditions for the determinant. I got these by setting the inverse equal to the hermitian conjugate:

**Unitary Conditions**
\begin{eqnarray}
a=\overline{ei-hf}\\
b=\overline{gf-di}\\
c=\overline{dh-ge}\\
d=\overline{ch-bi}\\
e=\overline{ai-gc}\\
f=\overline{bg-ah}\\
g=\overline{bf-ce}\\
h=\overline{dc-af}\\
i=\overline{ae-bd}
\end{eqnarray}

**Determinant Examples**
\begin{eqnarray}
a(ei-hf)-b(di-gf)+c(dh-ge)=1\\
|ei-hf|^2+|gf-di|^2+|dh-ge|^2=1\\
|a|^2+|b|^2+|c|^2=1 \;\;\; \text{etc.}
\end{eqnarray}

Now in trying to construct a chart, going by the fact $a,\ldots,i \in \mathbb{C}$, there are 18 real degrees of freedom/9 complex. Since $\mathbb{C}^4 \cong \mathbb{R}^8$, I think it may be easier to work with $\mathbb{C}^4$, since you can always express the matrix entries explicitly using four entries.

And then this is where I think it best to write out a chart, say for $U_a :=\{ei-hf\neq 0 \Leftrightarrow a\neq 0\}$, which is open, as 
$$\phi_a : U_a \longrightarrow \phi_a(U_a) \subseteq GL_2(\mathbb{C}) \subseteq \mathbb{C}^4 
$$
$$\phi_a (\left(\begin{smallmatrix}a&b& c\\ d & e & f\\ g & h & i\end{smallmatrix}\right)) = (e,f,h,i) \;\;\;\text{equivalently} \left(\begin{smallmatrix}e & f\\h& i\end{smallmatrix}\right)
$$

Then, trying to invert it, things go a bit awry, and when I try to recalculate the explicit inverse, my construction seems to fail, since everytime I try to include the unitary condition and determinant condition in general, things go funny.

Any ideas would be really appreciated!